# How can I get the version of portlets in liferay 7 + OSGI?

Tags: version-control, liferay, liferay-7

How is it possible to get the versions of .war portlets of liferay 7.

For example in liferay 6.2 I had a .war, then it was exploded inside the tomcat webapps folder and I could get the versions with another script by just looking at some proeprties like the following:

```
TMP="$(cat $LIFERAY_FOLDER/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/MyPortlet/WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.xml | awk -v FS="(MyPortlet-portlet/|/war)" '{print $2}' | grep "^.")"
echo -e "MyPortlet:\t\t\t$TMP" >> $OUTPUT_FILE
```

Or get the versions of some static files inside the porlet:

```
TMP="$(cat $LIFERAY_FOLDER/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/MyPortlet/WEB-INF/src/content/Language_de.properties | awk -v FS="(TEXT_VERSION = )" '{print $2}' | grep "^.")"
echo -e "Text version of MyPortlet:\t\t$TMP">> $OUTPUT_FILE
```

How is it possible to have this versioning functionality in a production server with liferay 7.1+?

I need to be able to check automatically for the versions currently deployed. The gogo tool is not enabled in production mode by default, and I´ve found that the telnet access sometimes crashes the whole tomcat so is a no go option. And even so I´ve only seen that it allows to access toa  bundle version but in anyway to some static files.

Thanks.

Comment: the manifest contains the bundle-version...

Answer (score 1):

One way is to expose a custom remote service via /api/jsonws (with guest access) only to have the version.

You can retrieve the current bundle version using this code:

```
public String getVersion() {

    Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(XXXXImpl.class);

    return bundle.getVersion().toString();
}
```

Comment: But this solution still does not allow you to get the versions of some properties inside the portlet like the languages.

Comment: That's typically tightly coupled to the bundle version, no?

Comment: @OlafKock it is, but is slow and time consuming in an environment which contains multiple portlets.

Comment: "slow and time consuming" as in: The code from Daniele's answer takes a lot of CPU cycles? Daniele's answer provides a proper answer, unless you state that you need a different kind of version. What else than a bundle version would you need? And what keeps you from generating a lookup table of bundle-version to whatever-you-need-version during your build time, when you probably have that version available?

Answer (score 0):

you can get a portlet version from gogo shell.

commands:

```
lb - list of bundles
b bundle_id - details of the bundle.
```